# Recursive function to calculate matrix multiplication

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

I'm trying to write a recursive function to calculate matrix multiplication.

**EDITED :**

This is the code :

```
def mult_mat(x, nbr):
    result = [[2, 4],
              [1, 3]]

    if nbr == 1:
        return result
    else:
        for i in range(len(x)):
            for j in range(len(result[0])):
                for k in range(len(result)):
                    result[i][j] += x[i][k] * result[k][j]
        mult_mat(result, nbr-1)

    return result


m = [[2, 4],
      [1, 3]]

# the number of times m1 will be multiplied
n = 3
res = mult_mat(m, n)
for r in res:
    print(r)
```

As an example, for `n = 3` I am trying to get the result:

`m1 * m1` will be  `[[8, 20], [5, 3]] = result` and `result * m1` will be `[[36, 92], [23, 59]]` and so on.

the output of this code is:

```
[10, 24]
[44, 108]
```

and what i want is this :

```
[36, 92]
[23, 59]
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: From a quick glance, your function returns `result`, but when you recurse, you pass it on as `y`, which isn't modified.

Comment: You're also both iterating and recursing.  Presumably you want to do one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Thank you ! I edited the code, but the problem remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's understand conceptually what you want to achieve with recursion. You want to multiply a matrix, `M`, with itself. `mult_mat(M, 2)` will give `M * M`, therefore, `mult_mat(M, 1)` just returns `M` itself.

In the multiplication, you have 3 matrices going on. `x` and `y` are the two matrices you're multiplying together, which you store in `result`. Now, let's look what happens for the first few multiplications.

```
x * x             # n = 2

x * (x * x)       # n = 3
                  # here, we initially calculate x * x,
                  # which we pass as y in the next stack for x * y
```

As you can see, for `n = 2`, you multiply `x` by itself, but for `n > 2`, `y` is different than `x`, so you must pass it on to the function somehow. We can code this idea as follows.

```
def mult_mat(x, nbr, y=None):
    if nbr == 1:
        # if y is None, it means we called `mult_mat(x, 1)`, so return `x`
        if y is not None:
            return y
        return x

    if y is None:
        y = x
    result = [[0, 0],
              [0, 0]]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(result[0])):
            for k in range(len(result)):
                result[i][j] += x[i][k] * y[k][j]
    return mult_mat(x, nbr-1, result)

m = [[2, 4],
      [1, 3]]

# the number of times m1 will be multiplied
n = 3
res = mult_mat(m, n)
for r in res:
    print(r)
```

It's may look like ugly code and that's probably because there are better ways to achieve what you want without recursion. However, I couldn't think of a different way while implementing recursion. My solution logically flowed from the points I laid out at the beginning.